# Javascript web server?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to build a micro (proof of concept) web server in Javascript?

Has anyone done this before?.

---

**EDIT:** *Apparently explicit clarification is needed here. The question is ultimately about how to push data from the server to the browser after the initial request made by the browser has been closed. In other words, how to make the browser accept subsequent requests initiated by a server.*

*Does a javascript based web server need to be installed into the browser, or is there some other method?*

Comment: To clarify, the reason for my question is to be able to implement a kind of "poor man's" callback mechanism over HTTP. In otherwords, I want to be able to run the webserver in the client browser, so that a remote server can send data to the (embedded server in) the client browser. Sounds confusing, but hopefully, you get my point..

Comment: Perhaps you should google for "web sockets", but I don't think you're going to be able to implement an architecture quite like what you describe.

Comment: Node.js runs on the server (as the name _web-server_ suggests).

Comment: What you really want is patrick dw's answer: use comet. What you think you want is impossible and in fact reflects a poor understanding of how HTTP works.

Comment: Regardless of what he needs, what he is asking for is more interesting. Is it possible to run a web server from JavaScript in a browser? Is it possible to open and listen on a socket from JavaScript loaded in a browser? If the answer is yes then a JavaScript web server is definitely possible. Someone just needs to implement http protocol to receive and respond to requests. That would mean you could push JavaScript to someones browser that starts a web server that responds to http requests. It might be useless without access to the filesystem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're saying that you want to be able to push data to browsers that have initiated contact with your server, I'd do some research on Comet servers.

I don't know anything about it, so I'll just pass off a couple links to you that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

[From Wikipedia Comet_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

> Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.[1](http://www.ape-project.org/) Comet is an umbrella term, encompassing multiple techniques for achieving this interaction. All these methods rely on features included by default in browsers, such as JavaScript, rather than on non-default plugins. The Comet approach differs from the original model of the web, in which a browser requests a complete web page at a time.[3]

Here's something called APE. I don't know a thing about it, but you may find it helpful.

[From the APE site:](http://www.ape-project.org/)

> APE is a full-featured OpenSource solution designed for Ajax Push. It includes a comet server and a Javascript Framework. APE allows to implement any kind of real-time data streaming to a web browser, without having to install anything on the client-side.

Comment: THATS what I'm talking about!. Saves me having to reinvent the wheel

Comment: maybe the question is poorly frame but i do not get at all what this has to do with a JS web server?? Pointy's answer is good, though!

Comment: @oberhamsi: So you down-voted me? Turns out that this was *exactly* what OP wanted. Take the time to read the comment above yours. It is from the OP stating that it answered the question. The reason I left this answer was that I did what you obviously didn't take the time to do. I read through the dialogue in the other comments, and deduced that this was what OP needed, but didn't know how to phrase it. If you do the same, you'll see that OP wanted to *originate* requests from the server to the browser, which only makes sense if the browser made an initial request. Well at least you commented.

Answer (score 16):

Check out the RingoJS project, or Node.js.  The answer is "yes", and not just "micro" or "proof of concept".

[RingoJS](http://www.ringojs.org/)

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

[express.js framework for node](http://expressjs.com/)

*edit* — This question is extremely old. If you want more information on this topic, it's certainly the case that better resources online have been created over the past 11 years.

Comment: Vame accross nodeJS a couple of days ago. It isn't clear to me if code written using node.js can be run in a browser (which is what I'm trying to do). Can you confirm if a webserver written using node.js can be run in an ordinary browser?

Comment: @skyeagle: What do you mean by _"run in a browser"_?

Comment: No, node.js is a **server-side** technology. It is Javascript-based, so of course *some* code could be common between browser and server, but you can't really implement a server in a browser for a lot of reasons.

Comment: @elusive: meaning I can save the code in webserver.js and reference the script in webserver-example.html and get the browser to load (and run) the webserver.js script

Comment: No, I don't think you're going to be able to convince the browser to listen on a socket.  As I wrote in another comment, you may want to read about "web sockets".

Comment: @skyeagle: That is impossible. The server needs to know how to handle HTTP-requests and -responses (and a lot of other things). This cannot be implemented in JavaScript. You cannot execute anything except JavaScript in a browser (this is why applications like Node.js are required in between).

Answer (score 1):

There's an add-on for Firefox (also available as a separate desktop application) called [Plain Old Webserver](http://davidkellogg.com/wiki/Main_Page). It's supposed to be able to run a special kind of server-side JavaScript that has access to all the internal features of the web browser, including local file and SQLite database access, access to browser preferences and history, and anything else that can be done with a Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Juggernaut?
https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut/blob/master/README.md
You'll have to forgive, I'm not sure if this exactly what you are looking for, and am a bit of a noob, but the readme made it sound like good fit for what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

## JS HTTPD

http://acme.com/software/js_httpd/

Is a small UNIX HTTP server written in JavaScript.

It runs from inetd, which means its performance is poor. But for low-traffic sites, it's quite adequate. It implements all the basic features of an HTTP server, including:

- Security against ".." filename snooping.
- The common MIME types.
- Trailing-slash redirection.
- index.html
- Directory listings.

js_httpd can also be used to serve HTTPS by wrapping it with stunnel. Instructions are included.

Other tiny and/or weird web servers (all run from inetd):

http://acme.com/software/js_httpd/

Comment: The title of this Q&A should be changed to reflect that javascript web servers are not asked for :) I was too going to inform about a javascript web server that can be used for unit tests or what not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Httpd.js/HTTP_server_for_unit_tests

Answer (score 0):

You could try "ewsjs is an embedded Web server inside your browser. When developing Ajax-based and single-page-applications, it is often very difficult to test these applications until a Web server is in place. (...)

EWS provides an embedded Web server that looks to your Ajax application as if it is coming from the server. You can put in any logic and fully test out your Ajax application within the browser, without running a server.

EWS supports several key features: Registering handlers for any path, Registering handlers for parametrized paths (like Sinatra routes), Registering a handler for automatic (when no other handler matches), Rewriting of one path to another (like in Apache or nginx), Asynchronous (exactly mimicking true ajax calls)"

on https://github.com/deitch/ewsjs