# How can i test web application mirror using webcam? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, testing, server, webcam

I want to do a basic web application mirror using webcam.

Should I load this index.html file to server?

I am using [VideoIO](http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/index.html).

How can i test this html file?
Also, this file just a mirror application. How I can test my application end to end?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];  
}
</script>

  </head>
  
  <body class="sidebar-right">
  
  <table style="width: 800px;">
<tr><td colspan="2"><center>
<input id="url1" type="text" value="rtmfp://stratus.rtmfp.net/d1e1e5b3f17e90eb35d244fd-c711881365d9/" style="width:410px;"/>
</center></td></tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td>
 <center>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
   id="video1" width="480" height="360"
   codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
   <param name="movie" value="VideoIO.swf" />
   <param name="quality" value="high" />
   <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
   <param name="flashVars" value="controls=true" />
   <embed src="VideoIO.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000"
    width="480" height="360" name="video1" align="middle"
    play="true" loop="false" quality="high"
    allowFullScreen="true"
    allowScriptAccess="always"
                flashVars="controls=true"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
   </embed>
 </object>
 <!-- <input id="live1" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"
    onclick="getFlashMovie('video1').setProperty('live',
        document.getElementById('live1').checked)"/> -->
 </center>
 <center>
  <input id="publish1" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width:50px;"
    value="volkan"/>
  <br/>
  <input id="nearID1" type=Text" autocomplete="off" style="width:250px;"/>
  <br/>
  <input value="set" type="button" 
    onclick="getFlashMovie('video1').setProperty('src',
    document.getElementById('url1').value
    + '?publish=' + document.getElementById('publish1').value)"/>
  <input value="reset" type="button" 
    onclick="getFlashMovie('video1').setProperty('src', null)"/>
 </center>
</td></tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at HTML getUserMedia() browser API instead of flash plugins. [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) is a good article. You need to host the site locally to test web cam features in this case.

Comment: How can i run this example in locally?

Comment: I used SimpleHTTPServer.
You can look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230706/javascript-web-server).

Comment: To host locally, you can install LAMP/ WAMP stack on your PC, check out on google on how to install them and host files on localhost